# How to return multiple image from input file html In javascript

Tags: javascript, image, loops

i want to upload multiple image with JS and convert to JSON format each image, this is my code

```
function save() {
var file = document.querySelector("#image").files;

let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
    arr.push({
        image : file[i].name
    })
}
let json = JSON.stringify(arr)
console.log("JSON", json)


    
// }
```

}

i try to get image files with this :

```
var file = document.querySelector("#image").files;
```

image is multiple form , when i click button Add image, input file added like this:

[image]

if look based from input image, there are 2 images ,

1. products.png
2. petty cash.png

the problem is when i `console.log(json)` which json variable is convert arr variable have push inside loop with image name, but when i console.log(json), and see inspect element in browser, response just 1 image name, like this,

```
JSON [{"image":"products.png"}]
```

i expect response 2 image name like this:

```
  JSON [{"image":"products.png"},{"image":"petty cash.png"}]
```

response browser like this, JSON just return 1 image name

[image]

whats wrong from my code ? and how to solved this ?
Thanks

Comment: The two JSON codes, which you post at the end of your question are the same.

Comment: iam sory i  have edited question, in case i just get result 1 JSON image name, i expect 2 name in JSON

Comment: I must say this is an interesting problem. Have you tried just printing **arr** to the console? What does that return?

Comment: At the moment you only get the file from one file input with `document.querySelector("#image").files`. You also need to get the file from the other file input.

Comment: @Joachim i have edited my question with scresnhoot response from inspect element browser

Comment: document.querySelector("#image").files is one id , because i create dynamic add when click Add item, input file automatic added

Comment: @Marka if that’s the case, then why are you expecting to see *two* items printed to the console? That’s your problem! :)

Comment: how to result 2 iamge name with dynamic input file ? any idea ? i have stuck with this ? @Joachim

Comment: @Marka you need to put the code where you create **arr** *outside* the **save()** function.

Comment: can you give me example code ? @Joachim

Comment: @Marka you need to put this code: ***let arr = []*** just above the ***save()*** function. The answer below is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you only get the file from one file input with `document.querySelector("#image").files`. You also need to get the file from the other file input.

You can do that for example like this:

```
function save() {
    const fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]');

    let arr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < fileInputs.length; i++) {
        const files = fileInputs[i].files
        if (files.length > 0) {
            for (const file of files) {
                arr.push({
                    image : file.name
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added the if clause to prevent any errors, if one of the inputs doesn't contain a file.

It looks like you will only have one file per file input, but I still gave you a solution, which can handle multiple files per file input.

This solution can get the file names of all files in every file input.

EDIT: Sorry, it has to be `files.length` and not `files.size`. I have been using Java for too long... xD

Comment: i have replace my code with this code, but when i try console.log outsode for loop, just return empty array